# Simple scroll action not working with Appium Android Webdriver.io v5 Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, webdriver-io, appium-android

I am seriously struggling with such a simple task. I just want to scroll in my app from the bottom to the top and vice versa.

The documentation on appium.io is super outdated (trash). The webdriver.io documentation only works for browsers.

webdriver.io v5 api documentation: https://webdriver.io/docs/api.html

appium.io documentation: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/

Does someone has an example for a simple scroll to bottom and to the top?

Would appriciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good example in the appium-boilerplate project:

https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate.git

In that project is a file called Gestures.js that contains some very useful functions. In my case I wanted to swipe left or right. I used that JS class like this:

```
    Gestures.swipeLeft();
    Gestures.swipeRight();
```

The default on those functions is 1 percent. That did the trick for me.

And yes I agree, the documentation is not great and seemingly simple things take ages :-(

Comment: Oh and BTW, that snippet works both for iOS and Android

Comment: https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/blob/14e1550e9c535d6719a3a26dcc8bbedd82c2d929/tests/helpers/Gestures.js check here..